# hardware compatibility

Tags: hardware-rec

I am building a computer and wanted to confirm hardware compatibility, here we go:

- Seagate ST2000DL003 SY LP Hard Drive - 2TB, 5900RPM, 64MB, SATA-6
- Corsair Vengeance 12GB DDR3 RAM
- Intel BOXDX58SO2 Socket LGA1366 Motherboard
- Intel core i7-920 processor
- VGA 01G-P3-1461-KR GeForce GTX 560 Superclocked Video Card

For the motherboard I was wondering if it would work without a graphics card.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those specs should work together, but your hard drive will be a real bottleneck which is likely to negatively impact your actual user experience and perceived speed for many tasks.  I suggest you go for the Western Digital Raptor (64mb cache, 7200 rpm ... even go down to 1TB if you have to and get more as required) or, if you run linux, a combined small SSD for programs and your hdd for files.  If you put together a lovely system like that and then skimp a few bucks on the hard drive, you will regret it.

Also, I wouldn't bother with a clocked GTX 560, the stock (with good cooling) should last long enough to get out of date while  a clocked one will give you barely noticeable (practically placebo)  benefit but will likely die before it is out of date.  Putting the cash saved towards a better HDD will give you a better overall system.

also, when you get it, consider running without a swap (page) file, since you have so much ram, it would probably work out well for you ;)